# How to make the files load properly in Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I am trying to create a server for my game. The files don't load and work properly when i run it through `localhost:2000` but when i run it through `localhost:2000/client/index.html` all the CSS and JS files seem to work. How can I make it so that it will work when i run it through `localhost:2000`?

Here is my folder hierarchy:

```
app.js
--client--
  index.html
  --js--
    mainGame.js
    (a bunch of other JS files)
  --css--
    gameStyle.css
    militaryUnitStyle.css
  --(all my other folders)--
--node_modules--
  (all my node libraries)
--server--
  (nothing in it)
```

To be clear I would like it to run `/client/index.html` when you run it through `localhost:2000`

This is the server code in `app.js`

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var serv = require('http').Server(app)
var port = 2000
var serverMSG = '[server] '

let serverInfo = {
    currentPlayers: 0,
    maxPlayers: 4,
    serverMax: 128,
}
let player = {
    civ: {
        england: false,
        france: false,
        spain: false,
        dutch: false,
    },
    states: {
        lobby: true,
        civSelect: false,
        game: {
            general: false,
            victory: false,
            defeat: false,
        },
    },
}

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html')
})
app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'))

serv.listen(port)
console.clear()
console.log('Colonial Warfare server => initialized!')
console.log('CWserver HostPort: ' + port)


var io = require('socket.io') (serv,{})
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    if(serverInfo.currentPlayers < serverInfo.maxPlayers) {
    console.log(serverMSG + 'Socket connection')
    serverInfo.currentPlayers++
    console.log(serverMSG + 'Current players on server => ' + serverInfo.currentPlayers)
    }
    if(serverInfo.currentPlayers == serverInfo.maxPlayers) {
        console.log(serverMSG + 'Game ready to begin!')
    }
    // if(serverInfo.currentPlayers > serverInfo.maxPlayers) {
    //     console.log('Max players reached! Wait for someone to disconnect or wait for match to be over to connect.')
    // }

    if(serverInfo.currentPlayers == 0) {
        console.log(serverMSG + 'Server Empty')
    }
    socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
        console.log(serverMSG + 'Client disconnected')
        serverInfo.currentPlayers--
        console.log(serverMSG + 'Current players on server => ' + serverInfo.currentPlayers)
      });
})
```

Keep in mind I am also a beginner at Node.js

Comment: Please show a css tag or a script tag that you have this problem with so we can see how you're specifying the URL in the page.  You should be using a URL that starts with `/` so it's not relative to the path of the page.  Then, you can adjust your `express.static()` so that it properly handles a non-varying URL for all your static resources.

Comment: This is the CSS part in the HTML `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/gameStyle.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/militaryUnitStyle.css">` and this is the JS part  `<script  src="./js/recruitMenu.js"></script>
  <script  src="./js/capitalColonySelect.js"></script>
  <script  src="./js/nativeSettlements.js"></script>
  <script  src="./js/cityPicker.js"></script>
  <script  src="./js/settlementShortcuts.js"></script>
  <script  src="./js/mainGame.js"></script>
  <script  src="./js/eventListeners.js"></script>`

Comment: Change ALL your page URLs to start with `/`, not with `.`.  You want a constant URL coming into the server that does not depend upon the path of the page.  Then, you can adjust your `express.static()` code to consistently work with that.  With you don't start with `/`, the browser adds the path of the page URL onto the start of this URL before requesting it, making the requested URL vary depending upon the page which is not what your server wants.  There are dozens of similar questions here as this is a common mistake.

Comment: I have changed everything to start with a `/` but I still get this message from the console: `Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:2000/css/gameStyle.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.` and this with the JS files `GET http://localhost:2000/js/recruitMenu.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: nevermind I got it to work. Thank you so much for the help!